# How get latest date from other 4 columns for each record?

Tags: postgresql

I have this select:

```
 SELECT  
     hre.workday_given_id           AS employee_id  
    ,pp.id                          AS job_id
    ,pp.id                          AS job_pk   
    ,pp.time_modified               AS job_modify_date  
    ,pps.time_modified              AS store_job_modify_date     
    ,tss.time_modified              AS store_job_assignment_modify_date 
    ,'?'                            AS time_modify_date    
    ,cas.time_modified              AS store_modify_date
    FROM ...
```

I need time_modify_date  -- this is latest date from other 4 date columns.
Please help me to create the query. Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrBdY.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `greatest()` function:

```
greatest(pp.time_modified, pps.time_modified, tss.time_modified, cas.time_modified) as time_modify_date
```